# Why was the production of the animated TV series "Invincible" suspended?

Tags: production, invincible

The first season of [*Invincible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_(TV_series)) (TV series) had eight episodes.

The second season had only four episodes, and the story ended inconclusively.

Why was the production of the animated TV series *Invincible* suspended?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There were unspecified '*production problems*' that delayed the second season, presumably because the show was more successful than Amazon thought it would be, and the second season attracted a larger budget (mo money = mo problems).

> "It's a little bit of the production process just because ramping
> things up has taken a lot longer than we thought," he said.

The show was 'paused' mid-season because the show is being aired weekly (in order to promote subscriptions to *[Amazon Prime Video](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/video/storefront?contentId=IncludedwithPrime&contentType=merch&merchId=IncludedwithPrime)*). A delay in starting the show would have meant that the last four episodes would have encroached on the 'crowded' Christmas period, during the time that Amazon wanted to promote their Christmas films and shows.

> Kirkman then explained why the hiatus will be timed well. **"With
> everything going on in that time of year with Thanksgiving, Christmas,
> New Year's, and a lot of family time, I think a lot of shows get lost
> in the shuffle there, and so I think it's good to take a pause**. And
> narratively, it's gonna make things hit a little bit harder. And
> people will know what I'm talking about when the season launches."
>
> Beyond the logistical reasons, he believes that, with how the story of
> Season 2 is structured, a mid-season break may be just what fans need.
> He specifically sites another series based on his work, The Walking
> Dead, as an example of how such a split can build anticipation with a
> shocking plot point that leaves viewers both catching their breath and
> clamoring for more. **"But also this is something that we've done with
> every season of The Walking Dead, and I think narratively, it's kind
> of cool to have that pause to digest what you've just experienced,"** he
> added. It seems Invincible has just that kind of punch in store before
> it'll go on hiatus. **"And when you see Episode 4 of Season 2, you may
> need a break. It's a big episode. It's definitely a mid-season finale
> kind of episode."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Collider: Robert Kirkman Explains Why 'Invincible' Season 2 Was Split Into Two Parts](https://collider.com/invincible-season-2-two-part-release-robert-kirkman-comments/)</sup></sub>

Simply put, Invincible, a show boasting "*frequent graphic, gory, and brutal violence*" is not something you want to put next to *[*Candy Cane Lane*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21328106/)* on posters.

---

The 'split' was largely due to having the first four episodes ready and the second four not ready. Normally they would have simply delayed the airdate, but Amazon seem to have pressured them to get *something* out, even if it meant delaying the second half.

> **THH:** *Invincible Season 2 has finally arrived but we only got to see half of it, was this always meant to be a 2 part thing or was the
> decision made afterwards?*
>
> **SIMON:** *The decision was made afterwards. As we started producing the show, some issues came up, talked to Amazon, so we thought this
> was the best way to present the show, now, with these 4 episodes
> instead of making audience wait even longer. We will come back after a
> few months and give you the rest.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Co-Showrunner Simon Racioppa Talks About ‘Invincible’ Season 2](https://thehollywoodhandle.co/2023/animated/co-showrunner-simon-racioppa-talks-about-invincible-season-2-exclusive/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I haven't watched CCL, but a cross-over might be interesting. :)

Comment: @Barmar - I would watch that film

Comment: On a double bill with Pride and Prejudice and Zombies.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently it was not suspended at all, but Season 2 will be broadcast in two halves of 4 episodes each:

> The first half of the season, consisting of four episodes, premiered
> on November 3, 2023, with the last four set to debut in early 2024
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia - Invincible: Season 2 (2023–24)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_(TV_series)#Season_2_(2023%E2%80%9324))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

While the answers here are good, they seem to ignore a lawsuit brought on by the *Invincible* comics colorist, William Crabtree for royalties. This info comes from a [*Hollywood Reporter* article from November 29, 2023](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/business/business-news/invincible-copyright-suit-robert-kirkman-william-crabtree-trial-1235699142/amp/):

> ### ‘Invincible’ Profits Showdown Heading to Trial
>
> William Crabtree accused famed comic writer Robert Kirkman of duping him into signing a contract that characterized his contributions as a "work-for-hire," leaving him with no ownership stake in the series.

The crux of the lawsuit is William Crabtree’s claim that Robert Kirkman supposedly “tricked” Crabtree into signing his rights away via a “work for hire” agreement; thus cutting him out of royalties for derivative work such as the Amazon series.

> Crabtree’s breach of oral contract claim was also allowed to proceed, with Frimpong siding against Kirkman on arguments that it should be time-barred based on his repudiation in 2012 that Crabtree isn’t entitled to 10 percent of revenue generated from film or TV adaptations. **The four-year statute of limitations started on the claim, the court found, when Kirkman in 2020 refused to pay Crabtree for Amazon licensing the comic.**

And this additional info comes from a [*Yahoo! Entertainment* article from December 6, 2023](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/invincible-lawsuit-explained-william-crabtree-091525498.html):

> According to U.S. District Court Judge Maame Ewusi-Mensah Frimpong, Crabtree cannot move ahead with any statute of limitations on copyright disputes and fraud claims. **But he has been permitted to claim that the Certificate of Authorship is invalid and Kirkman had breached the oral agreement between them by not paying any royalties over the Amazon deal.** Now, the trial will begin in 2024 unless the two parties agree to settle before that.

That said, I can’t find a direct reference to this lawsuit resulting in production delays to the Amazon series. But one can assume that the lawsuit has had an impact on the series production.

Comment: It will have resulted in the makers having to spend time in depositions and meetings with their lawyers, if nothing else.